# How to configure pymssql with SSL support on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pymssql

What are the steps required to configure pymssql with SSL support on Ubuntu so I can connect to a SQL Server instance that requires an encrypted connection (e.g., Azure)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749308/2144390) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.)

The following worked for me on a clean install of Xubuntu 16.04 LTS x64:

The first challenge is that the FreeTDS we get from the Ubuntu 16.04 repositories does not support SSL "out of the box", so we need to build our own. Start by installing `python3-pip` (which also installs build-essentials, g++, and a bunch of other stuff we'll need) and `libssl-dev` (the OpenSSL libraries required for building FreeTDS with SSL support)

```
sudo apt install python3-pip libssl-dev
```

Download the source code for FreeTDS by clicking the "Stable Release" link at [freetds.org](http://www.freetds.org/). Unpack the archive, switch to the directory you just created (e.g., freetds-1.00.104), and then do

```
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl --enable-msdblib
make
sudo make install
```

Check the build with

```
tsql -C
```

and ensure that "TDS version: auto" and "OpenSSL: yes" are listed. Then use `tsql` to test a "raw" FreeTDS connection, e.g.,

```
tsql -H example.com -p 1433 -U youruserid -P yourpassword
```

Now to install pymssql. By default, recent versions ship as a pre-compiled "wheel" file that *does not* support encrypted connections so we need to install from the pymssql source. Starting with pymssql 2.1.4, the build process relies on Cython, so first do

```
pip3 install --user Cython
```

and then do

```
pip3 install --user --no-binary pymssql pymssql
```

When the build is complete, pymssql is installed.

But... it won't work (yet). When we try to do `import pymssql` in Python we get

> ImportError: libsybdb.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

because apparently that file is in the "wrong" place. The fix (ref: [here](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/8)) is to create a symlink in the "right" place that points to the actual file

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.so.5 /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5
sudo ldconfig
```

Now pymssql works with SSL connections.

For me, anyway.

Comment: Dude - awesome, thanks for the answer.  To add to the madness, it appears that OpenSSL 1.1 breaks the build on FreeTDS 0.95, so I had to back-version my openssl with 'apt-get install openssl1.0' to make it work on Ubuntu 18.04 - that worked for me.

Comment: @T3am5hark - I have added another answer specifically for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @GordThompson Following the steps I see that the encryption is turned on in freetds/pymssql. But when I check the SQL server side if the connection is encrypted, using this, SELECT *,encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections, I see that the encrypt_option='False'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sandesh - Are you connecting to Azure SQL? When I connect directly to a SQL Server instance on my LAN and do `SELECT encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id=@@SPID` it returns `'TRUE'`.

Comment: @GordThompson : Yes, I am connecting to Azure SQL.

Comment: @GordThompson : Moving away from pymssql, I am looking at pyodbc, are there any docs or info that you can point to on how to connect to Sybase using pyodbc?

Answer (score 6):

#### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

The Ubuntu 18.04 repositories will install a version of FreeTDS that supports GnuTLS so it is not absolutely necessary to build FreeTDS from source. However, we still need to build pymssql from source because simply doing the usual

```
pip3 install --user pymssql
```

will install a pre-compiled "wheel" that does not support secure connections. Instead, we need to do

```
sudo apt install python3-pip freetds-dev
pip3 install --user Cython
pip3 install --user --no-binary pymssql pymssql
```

Comment: I think I love you man, i spent whole days looking for that damn answer!

Comment: Gord, do you have solution for CentOS ?

Comment: @Nilesh - Sorry, no. I use pyodbc now.

Comment: @GordThompson Man, you have stopped me from crying on this one!  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 it seems that at least the Docker containers have a FreeTDS version that already supports SSL.

Also, at least for Python 2.7, Cython is not needed:

https://github.com/tds-fdw/ci-setup/blob/master/ubuntu16.04/Dockerfile (lines 23-39)

But there's something to keep in mind!

The TDS version to connect to Azure **must be forced to be at least 7.1** (or newer, depending on your needs: https://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)

Otherwise you will see the infamous:

> [ERROR] (20017, 'DB-Lib error message 20017, severity 9:\nUnexpected
>   EOF from the server\nNet-Lib error during Operation now in progress
>   (115)\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server
>   connection failed\n')

For some reason this was not needed for Ubuntu 14.04 and pymssql 2.1.3 without any extra configuration (https://github.com/tds-fdw/ci-setup/blob/master/ubuntu14.04/Dockerfile)

It can be done with either:

```
export TDSVER=7.1
```

Or, at the Python code, and at the connect function, adding the parameter:

```
 tds_version='7.1'
```

With that, I am able to to use pymssql 2.1.4 to connect to Azure without issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pymssql:2.2.0

first uninstall old pymssql:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pymssql
```

second install new pymssql:

```
sudo pip3 install "pymssql==2.2.0"
```

Comment: Yes, the recent version of `pymssql` should work as is. @xqlsrjjjh, please fix unbalanced quotation mark.