# Python - pymssql 2.1.3 and freetds compatability

Tags: python, azure, freetds, pymssql

So I have very little knowledge of what goes on behind the scenes, but I have an application that can connect to an Azure MSSQL database when ran on my Mac and will not when running on Ubuntu 12.04.  The only difference I can find is the version of freetds - I have freetds v1.00.15 on my Mac and freetds v0.91 on Ubuntu.  I'm currently using pymssql v2.1.3 in both environments.

Here is my code:

```
import pymssql
import datetime

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../credentials')
from mssqlcredentials import *

try:
    conn = pymssql.connect(
        server=myMSSQLserver,
        user=myMSSQLuser,
        password=myMSSQLpassword,
        database=myMSSQLdatabase,
        )

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''SELECT DISTINCT
        dr.DeliveryID
    FROM
        DeliveryRecords dr
    WHERE
        (OrganizationOwnerGroupId = '3f7dc2fa-50b5-4c6c-9c75-2009230791fe' OR
        OrganizationOwnerGroupId = '8b70c0a3-7189-48fe-816f-2c19d854665b') AND
        dr.Created <= DATEADD(MINUTE,-15,GETDATE()) AND
        dr.Created >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-45,GETDATE())''')

    DeliveryIDs = cursor.fetchall()

    conn.close()

except Exception, error:
    print error
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
(20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n')
```

Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: It sounds like FreeTDS/pymssql on your Ubuntu box is not configured to use SSL. Run `tsql -C` at a terminal prompt and see if it lists "OpenSSL: yes". In any case, have a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39395549/2144390) for ideas on how to get it set up.