# Error while connecting to Azure via pymssql on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, azure-sql-database, freetds, pymssql

I wrote a Python script called `test.py` that contains the following:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(host="hostname", user="username@hostname", password="pass", database="dbname")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SalesLT.Customer WHERE CustomerID=%d', 1)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[3]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()
```

I installed FreeTDS with the commands:

```
export PYMSSQL_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1
pip install pymssql
```

The install seemed to work, but I'm getting an error when I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 8, in <module>

 conn = pymssql.connect(host="hostname",user="username@hostname",password="pass",database="dbname")

File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
```

pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, 'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed\n')

I don't know what's wrong, and help would be appreciated. Please let me know if there are changes I need to make to `freetds.conf`.

Comment: Could you please include your `freetds.conf` file?

Comment: re: `user="username@hostname"` - Are you by chance trying to connect to an Azure SQL instance?

Comment: @GordThompson yes i am trying to connect to an Azure SQL instance.

Comment: @FlipperPA - here is freetds.config file

[MSSQL]
host = kesnshoodata.database.windows.net
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to connect to an Azure SQL instance

Azure requires an encrypted connection, and pymssql installed from the default `.whl` files or built with `PYMSSQL_BUILD_WITH_BUNDLED_FREETDS=1` does *not* support encrypted connections.

For instructions on using pymssql with encrypted connections under Ubuntu, see

[How to configure pymssql with SSL support on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39395548/2144390)

Comment: @gordthompson- according to provided link here 
I am trying to run sudo -H pip install --no-binary pymssql pymssql
but it's showing an error 

Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --no-binary

my pip -V is



pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

can you help me out with this

Comment: pip version 1.5.4 sounds like it is VERY old. The most recent version is 8.1.2. try `sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: i am able to do the connection by following these steps.