# Troubleshooting pymssql connection to Azure mssql on linux cloud at pythonanywhere

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, pythonanywhere, pymssql

I have not been able to connect to an Azure hosted MSSQL server through `pymssql` on pythonanywhere.
I have zero previous linux experience, so that is making it harder than it should.

I am trying this sample script provided with the instructions:

```
host = "123.456.789.012"
username = "yourusername"
password = "yourpassword"
database = "yourdatabasename"

conn = pymssql.connect(host, username, password, database)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
    File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
    File "_mssql.pyx", line 637, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:6581)
    File "_mssql.pyx", line 1630, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException (_mssql.c:17524)
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (my_server_name.database.windows.net:1433)\n')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (my_server_name.database.windows.net:1433)\n')
```

I figured it had to do with the TDS Version I am running, which I get to be `4.2` by running `tsql -C` on bash. Here is the output:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 4.2
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: yes
```

I have tried placing a `.freetds.conf` file both at `home/myuser/` and at `home/myuser/my_virtual_env/`, but that did not change any behavior. Should I have restarted the bash console or the python console? I did not think so. Here are the file contents:

```
[global]
        tds version = 7.1


[azure]
        tds version = 7.4
```

The other alternative would be to use pyodbc, but that would also involve configuring freetds and then some more, so it looks like there is nothing to be had there.

---

I should point out that I have `pymssql` connecting just fine to azure on my win10 machine with the following connection string:

```
arguments = dict(server=db_server_add, user=db_usn+"@my_server",
                                 password=db_pswd, database=db_name, charset="utf8")
AZURE_ENGINE = create_engine('mssql+pymssql:///', connect_args=arguments)
```

Comment: quick thing to double check- are you a free user? PythonAnywhere doesn't allow free users to make arbitrary external internet connections. They have a whitelist for free users.

Comment: @conrad, No. I signed for the lowest tier though, to get a feel for the service. I tried all the instructions available on site.

Comment: did you restart your consoles after upgrading?

Comment: @hwjp you mean upgrading to a paid account type? I created my account as paid from the beginning. Also, I did not restart any consoles, but I do have closed and opened many new consoles without change.

Comment: can you tell if you're running the same version of pymssql on your own PC as on PythonAnywhere?  Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: @hwjp Both should be the same version, as both are fresh installs, but I will be able to say for sure when I get home, in 4 hours. At home I use win10, though and PA is linux. On PA I am using `virtualenv` directly with directory `home/myuser/my_virtual_env/` whereas at home I am using a `conda` env.

Comment: @hwjp yes, they are both version 2.1.3

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39395548/2144390

Answer (score -1):

In Python Anywhere on a free account, it does not allow access to all web addresses. Only addresses from a specific list.

"If you have a paid Python Anywhere plan"

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MSSQLServer/

Comment: OP has a paid account, as mentioned in comments.