# Trying to connect to Sybase and Azure SQL server using python with TLS enabled connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database, sybase, pyodbc, pymssql

I am tyring to connect from AWS to Sybase database and Azure SQL server using python (pymssql) and have the TLS enabled on the connections. This does not seem work even after trying ([How to configure pymssql with SSL support on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395548/how-to-configure-pymssql-with-ssl-support-on-ubuntu)).

Details: The encryption is turned on in freetds/pymssql. tsql -C, shows that OpenSSL is enabled. But when I check the SQL server side if the connection is encrypted, using this, SELECT *,encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections, I see that the encrypt_option='False'

So, I am trying to see if pyodbc is the route that needs to be picked. Trying to see what are the odbc driver options for pyodbc to connect to Sybase with TLS enabled?

Comment: Your connection to Azure SQL *must* be encrypted. However, when you connect to Azure SQL you are probably not connecting directly to a SQL Server instance. Instead, you are likely connecting to a proxy. The connection between your client and the proxy is encrypted, but the connection between the proxy and the SQL Server instance may not be. That's why encrypt_option may be 'FALSE' for the corresponding row in sys.dm_exec_connections.

Comment: @GordThompson Is there a way to find or indicate that the Azure SQL connection is encrypted? Thanks!

Comment: Azure SQL connections are always encrypted, at least from the perspective of the client machine.

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect to Azure SQL, I used pyodbc and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.

In the pyodbc connect, I provided - Encrypt=YES;trustServerCertificate=Yes' in order to encrypt the connection and verified on the SQL server side, that the connection is encyrpted.

In order to connect to Sybase, I used pyodbc and FreeTDS driver with Encrypt=Yes option.